# App Store Connect page is not loading / too slow

Tags: macos, safari, app-store, app-store-connect

For 2 days I've been trying to access App Store Connect.

But the page is not loading even if I use Safari browser via Macbook.

I tried some other browsers as well. Opera and Chroma are a bit faster but still same issue.

What can I do for this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we are not Apple Developer support.

Comment: Did you fixed it? how? im having the same problem